# What is an example of a property which is not a topological property?

Tags: general-topology

A topological property of a topological space $X$ is the property that remains invariant under homeomorphisms.

So almost all properties of a topological space are topological property.

What is an example of a property which is not a **topological property** ?

I can see that **differentiability** is not a topological property though we do not bother about differentiability on a topological space.

Is it a good example ?

Comment: If a topological space has a metric (lengths, angles), that is not invariant. Is that the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: A (potentially stupid) property is the underlying set. Two homeomorphic spaces need not have the same underlying set.

Comment: @GuyInchbald, you are right, but i want to know more examples of $\text{not topological property}$ in a general topological space. Is there any?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR the metric is not a topological property, it is a metric property. This is basically why differentiability is not a topological property.

Comment: $x \in X$ is not a topological property. If $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic then $x \in X$ does not imply $x \in Y$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an example of what you are looking for is completeness of a metric space. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ and $(0,1)$ are homeomorphic, but one is complete, and the other is not. In the same vein, boundedness may not be preserved.

However, under an isometry, both of those properties are preserved.

Not sure if the following is non-trivial, but it was certainly surprising to me:

There are homeomorphic spaces s.t. embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$, their closures are not homeomorphic. An example is $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{S}^1 \setminus \{(0,1)\}$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$, which are homeomorphic (which can be seen via a stereographic projection onto $\mathbb{R}$), but their closures have different fundamental group. Another is $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ embedded into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Convexity is a slightly more surprising. It may seem topological, but it actually is not.

Comment: Can you show little calculation ?

Comment: Take the interval $[0,1]$ and the set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = x^2, x \in [0,1]\}$ i.e. the closed unit interval and a piece of a parabola. The former is convex, while the latter is not.

Comment: Consider the disk $D:=\{ (x, y, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^3\ |\ x^2+y^2\le 1\}$. This is convex, as every line segment connecting a pair of points in $D$ is contained in $D$. Next, let $N:=\{(x, y, z)\in S^2\ |\ z \ge 0 \}$ be the northern hemisphere. This is not convex. Let $p\colon N\to D$ be the projection $(x, y, z)\mapsto (x, y, 0)$, and let $i\colon D\to N, (x, y, 0)\mapsto(x, y, 1-(x^2+y^2))$. These are continuous and mutual inverses.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri, thank you

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR you are welcome.